# How to insert document.getElementById("xxx").src in an HTA?

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a project which is a HTA file, not HTML. So when I am trying to change the source of `<embed>` it does not work. I copied the whole source code and pasted it into a `.html` file, however when I place it into a `.hta` file it does not work. The code I have is the following:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Help Me !</title>
<script>
function Op()
{
    document.getElementById("Ct").src = "Anything.swf";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="Op()">Help</button>
<embed src="" Height="100%" Width="100%" id="Ct">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: **Now This Is Quite Hard And Annoying To Read.** _Please_ don't do this in the future.  Anyway, welcome to [so].  Make sure to read over [ask] before asking - it provides numerous tips on how to make sure your question gets the attention you want.

Comment: **Thanks Qantas 94 Heavy**

Comment: Why do you _need_ to have it in a `.hta` file?

Comment: I Am Working On A Project And For That I Want A App Not A Webpage.